# How to filter products by either brand or category in django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django blog, and I want to be able to filter products either by categories or brands.

```
**Page not found (404)**

**Request Method:   GET**

**Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/nestle/**

**Raised by:    shop.views.product_list**

**No Category matches the given query.**
```

The code works perfectly for a single instance but fails when I try to use both instances simultaneously. i.e. If I should comment either the brand or category, the code works well but both can't work together.

**Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/nestle/ ** -- nestle is a brand but the error raised is **No Category matches the given query.**. I wanted it to filter by brand and not by category

**This is my views.py file**

```
def product_list(request,  category_slug=None, brand_slug=None):
   category = None
   categories = Category.objects.all()
   products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

   brand = None
   brands = Brand.objects.all()
   products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

   if category_slug:
      category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
      products = products.filter(category=category)


    elif brand_slug:
       brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, slug=brand_slug)
       products = products.filter(brand=brand)
   


    return render(request,
       'shop/product/list.html',
       {'category': category,
       'categories': categories,
       'brand': brand,
       'brands': brands,
       'products': products})
```

**This is my model.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category',args=[self.slug])


class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'brand'
        verbose_name_plural = 'brands'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_brand',args=[self.slug])


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand,related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail',args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Can someone help me? Sorry I am a Newbie and trying to learn through tutorials. thanks

Comment: Why do you pass *two* slugs, how does the `urls.py` look like?

Comment: but here the `product_list_by_brand` will never "fire", since the previous URL matches all URLs that are matched by `product_list_by_brand`.

Comment: So please is there a way around it? Can you kindly help?

Comment: Thanx for your response. The intention was to get an independent slug for brand and category. This is how the urls.py looks like for the app                                              
 `from django.urls import path 
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
  
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list,name='product_list_by_category'),         
    path('<slug:brand_slug>/', views.product_list,name='product_list_by_brand'), 

    ] `